# Python doesn't kill proccess

Tags: python, process, kill

I want to kill all of the child processes of the `n` and also `n` its self. It works when I run the code form terminal but when I run the code in production mode (using `Nginx` ,`GUnicorn` and `systemd` and ...) It does not work.

NOTE: this is a part of a big code

NOTE: `n` is a `subprocess.Popen` object.

the child process is python jupyter notebook.

```py
 for n in notebooks:
        env = dict(os.environ)
        env['DISPLAY'] = ":0"
        subprocess.Popen(f'pkill -P {n.pid}',env=env,shell=True)
    return 'Done!',200
```

Comment: The user running the code in production mode might not have enough permissions,  Or you might be using different Python environments. Are there any error logs or messages?

Comment: @NK_ There is no error or log message - The process creator and killer are in same file and process created in same situation with the kill command and they are in same file so they have same Python env. Please help me if you can I need to solve this as soon as possible- thanks

Comment: also `pkill jupyter` works at terminal but doesn't work in production mode.Application creates processes in production mode but it does not kill them in this mode. But in development mode it works excellent.

Comment: Yes there is a log. Both the kill command and if there is an error (like permissions) that error will both get logged (well at least default Ubuntu does ;) ). Check `/var/log/` for a file that got updated.

Comment: @Rinzwind No there is no log or error.I checked, then posted this question